# How would I write this in IEEE standards?

Tags: binary, floating-point

I would like to know how to write 5/32 in IEEE754 standard. Is there a shortcut to do the fraction part?

The answer is `0 10000010 00100000000000000000000`. But there has to be an easier way to write 5/32 into this format than converting it to binary first.

Comment: Actually, 5/32 = 0 01111100 01000000000000000000000, which matches your answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you can do this to get the decimal numbers a lot faster. 5 (base 10) = 101 (Binary) and 32 = 1/(2^5). So 5/32 is just 101x2^-5